# Parsing return and call using ptrace

Tags: c, assembly, ptrace

I am coding a ftrace program in C for my school project, and I use ptrace() syscall to parse the instruction.
I count the call opcode (0x9a, 0xe8, 0xff when the bits (5,4,3) of the byte right after 0xff correspond to CALL) and the ret copcode (0xc3, 0xc2, 0xca, 0xcb).
Heres the program I trace :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     chevre(char *lel)
{
  printf("Chevre\n");
  free(lel);
  return (420);
}

int     main()
{
  char  *lel;

  lel = malloc(42);
  chevre(lel);
  return (0);
}
```

My question is: Why do I get 777 calls for only 751 returns? And why is there so many calls when I got only a few functions (Which I success to find parsing the ELF-file executable and the .plt section) ?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
The problem was in filtering the 0xff opcode: I was trying to read the byte at adress RIP - 8, which is part of the first parameter since the stack grows down and the instruction information were at adress RIP + 8.
Reading the opcodes I told I read is valid.

Comment: The `printf` function is relatively high-level, and will call other lower-level function which in turn does multiple system calls. Then you have to think about that the code you make is linked to some startup code, the `main` function is where your code starts running,. but it's not where the program starts, there are lots of code, and with that many calls, that have to happen before *and* after the `main` function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sounds like an answer to me :) // Also, +1 for the goat.

Comment: I get the __libc_start_main at call n° 678, so I guess before that is libc loading and stuff like that.
But is the difference between call number and ret number a mistake from me or is it normal?
(EDIT: the printf function is a macro if I am right, and the real function is puts)

Comment: `printf` is not a macro, but the compiler may replace a constant `printf` that ends with a newline with a `puts`.